# Laravel dynamic content from database clicking on navbar using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using laravel 7.I am new in laravel and ajax . I have a 'product's name' navbar. I want , When I click on a product from the navbar , the details of the product will show in a div without reloading the page. demo : ( https://www.webslesson.info/2017/03/dynamic-content-load-using-jquery-ajax-php.html ) the demo is in PHP, I want to use this in laravel.

blade part:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php
    $group = DB::table('package')->where('group_id', 5)->get();

    ?>
    @foreach ($group as $item)
        <li id="{{ $item->package_id }}"><a href="#">{{$item->package_name  }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
<span id="page_details"></span>
```

scipt part for ajax on blade file

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function load_page_details(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/getmsg',
                data: '_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
                data: {id: id},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#page_details').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        load_page_details(1);

        $('.nav li').click(function () {
            var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
            load_page_details(page_id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

route:

```
Route::post('/getmsg','AjaxController@index');
```

controller:

```
public function index(Request $request) 
{
    $pack_id=$request->id;
    $msg = DB::table('package')->where('package_id',$pack_id);
    $output .= '
    <h1>'.$msg->package_id.'</h1>
    
    ';

    return  $output;
 }
```

Please help me to make a thing in laravel like the demo  ( http://demo.webslesson.info/dynamically-loading-content-with-ajax/# )

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have 2 `data` properties on your ajax request. Make that as 1 :

`data: { "_token" : "{{ csrf_token() }}", "id" : id}`

Then, I would recommend setting `dataType` to `json` in the AJAX request, and from the controller returning a [json response](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#json-responses), instead of the `$output = ..` bit.

`return response()->json(['package_id' => $msg->package_id]);`

After that, from your `.success` callback, you can access the properties of `data` just as you would with a normal javascript object. To achieve what you want you can use `$('#page_details').html(data.package_id)`.

Comment: still not getting the result,

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 function load_page_details(id)
 {
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/getmsg',
    data: { "_token" : "{{ csrf_token() }}", "id" : id},
    dataType: "json", 
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#page_details').html(data.package_id)
   }
  });
 }

 load_page_details(1);

 $('.nav li').click(function(){
  var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
  load_page_details(page_id);
 });
 
 
});
</script>

Comment: public function index(Request $request) {
        $pack_id=$request->id;
        $msg = DB::table('package')->where('package_id',$pack_id);
       
        
        return response()->json(['package_id' => $msg->package_id]);
     }

Comment: If you're still getting a 500 error, it would be helpful to take a look in storage/logs/laravel.log file to see exactly why the request is failing and post it here.